# Can't figure out formula for duration on gSheet

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a gSheet that is fed from form submission. Throughout the day, I need to calculate the duration automatically; subtracting the most recent timestamp from the previous timestamp of the same user in column E. Is this possible?

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_gbM2TVpUDrGU0B0_s1_aiH2r-9l6TUPxwlzo2SW338/edit#gid=0

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula in E2

```
=IF(B2="", ,IF(XLOOKUP($B2,$B$1:$B1,$A$1:$A1,"-",0,-1)="-","First time worker",$A2-XLOOKUP($B2,$B$1:$B1,$A$1:$A1,,0,-1)))
```

And drag it down till the end of the sheet

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=IF(A2="",, SORTN(IF(
            COUNTIF(B$2:B2, "="&B2)>1=TRUE, 
            SORTN(FILTER(A$2:A2,B$2:B2=B2 ), 2, , 1, 0), A2),1,,1,1))
```

[image]